# Appropriate gauge wire for 12V 1 ampere power supply?

Tags: voltage, antenna, amperage, 12v, wire-size

I am looking to power a Wineguard 12V antenna amplifier from a PC power supply, but I don't know what gauge wire is right. The run will be about 4 feet total (2 ft each direction) at 12V with a draw less than 1 ampere. (I am unsure of the exact draw but I have powered it with 12V 500mA no problem.)

Would a 24 gauge wire with a 3.5mmOD 1.3mm ID barrel jack be sufficient? I'm worried it may be thin and the next largest size I have is 22 until I jump to 18 which seems a bit large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the specs for the AWG standard ([maybe here](https://powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm)) it states that the 24 gauge should be able to withstand 3.4A, so it should be fine.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I did see that exact link and many others but have used a few wire size calculator and they all seem to say 20 is about the minimum.  I believe it should be safe as well just would rather be safe then sorry. Thank You

Comment: If you consider this answers your question please mark it as "answered", and if you don't also do that. This can help the site a lot. Someone else may provide you with more insight on this topic.